# 3 column layout or 2 column layout if sidebar is present

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We have a dynamic number of radio buttons that we would like to display in 3 columns. However, if there is a sidebar present (e.g. a div on the side with some text), then we want to layout the radio buttons in 2 columns and the sidebar would take up the space where the 3rd column would go. Example images are below. Is this possible using only CSS?

**Things we have tried**

We have implemented a solution using React by dynamically changing the class name depending on the number of columns to use, i.e. this was not a CSS solution but a React solution. This works, however there may be layout changes in the future where a CSS only solution would be more flexible.

**Some things to note**

- This is not a responsive design question - the layout should change depending on the presence of the sidebar, not the size of the screen.
- Ideally this would be a pure-css solution.
- We are using Boostrap if that helps.

**3 Column Layout example**

[image: 3 columns]

**2 Column Layout with sidebar example**

[image: 2 columns with sidebar]

**Edit:**

Some code we have tried so far. We are using React to add the class names 'col2' or 'col3' depending on the layout we want:

```css
.item {
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #f32a9b;
  padding: 20px;
}

.col3 .col {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.col2 .col {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<h2>3 cols</h2>
<div class="container col3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>2 cols with sidebar</h2>
<div class="container col2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col sidebar">
    sidebar text. sidebar text. sidebar text. sidebar text. sidebar text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can wrap it inside `flex-wrap ` then set specific width to each of them. i think it's easiest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FatimaMazhit. Are you able to expand a bit more on that? `flex-wrap` can be used to ensure the items wrap to the following lines and setting a fixed width can be used to determine the number of items displayed in a row. How does it switch between showing 2 or 3 items per row depending on the presence of the sidebar?

Comment: I was talking about smth like that [https://jsfiddle.net/m65vqzhu/](https://jsfiddle.net/m65vqzhu/). just comment sidebar i was too lazy to add js ))

Comment: Post the code you've attempted

Comment: If you use bootstrap, share your code, so we can see and help from what you have.bootstrap is based on flex and flex-wrap, so it should not be a terrible issue to solve :)  https://jsfiddle.net/xtc2j8sd/

Comment: Sorry for not posting earlier. I have added our attempt at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try play through the selectors `:not()`, `:nth-last-child(n)` , `calc()` (to reset paddings) &  `background-clip` (could also be margin alone instead) and `grid-template-columns:1fr auto;` for the main container to shrink to zero the second *(auto)* column if empty *(no sidebar to put in it)*.

All together, it could be something alike:

```css
.item {
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: linear-gradient( #f32a9b, #f32a9b) no-repeat;
  background-clip: content-box;
  padding: 30px 20px calc(20px + 2.2em);
  margin-right: 30px;
  max-width: calc(calc(33vw - 40px) - 30px);
}

.col .row .col:not(.sidebar) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col .row:nth-last-child(2) .col:not(.sidebar) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.container.col {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- untouched HTML of yours aside the input which is a self closing tag -->
<h2>3 cols</h2>
<div class="container col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>2 cols with sidebar</h2>
<div class="container col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><input type="radio" name="radio">radio</input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col sidebar">
    sidebar text. sidebar text. sidebar text. sidebar text. sidebar text.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this issue with grid easily.

---

#### With sidebar

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #e91e63;
}

.side-bar {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item side-bar"></div>
</div>
```

#### Without sidebar

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #e91e63;
}

.side-bar {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 3 / -1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <!--<div class="grid-item side-bar"></div> -->
</div>
```